# Getting rid of the second elemnt in a matrix of 2D tuples

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to know how can I turn this matrix:

```
 [[(2,1)][(3,1)][(3,2)]
  [(2,3)][(3,1)]][(11,3)]]
```

into:

```
[(2)][3)][3)]
  [2][3]][11]]
```

that is, earising the second elements of the tuples that construct my matrix (thus making it a regular matrix of scalars). I would like to know how to do the opposite of this - taking a regular matrix and turn it into a matrix of lists or tuples.

Comment: What exactly is this `matrix`?  Is it a list of lists of tuples?   If a numpy array, what is its shape and dtype?  Object dtype, compound dtype, integer dtype?  Is that really your target?  with a mix of `()` and incomplete )?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to delete the second element of the tuple and the length of tuple is constant in the matrix:

```
res = [[(y[0],) for y in x] for x in input_array]
```

Comment: `res = [[(y(0)) for y in x] for x in input]` broken several ways: don't use Python keywords `input` as variable names, `y(0)` should use sq brackets `y[0]`, and to make the output still be a `tuple` you need a comma `(y[0],)`...`[[(y[0],) for y in x] for x in b]
Out[264]: [[(2,)], [(3,)], [(3,)], [(2,)], [(3,)], [(11,)]]`

Answer (score 0):

do you want to keep the tuples in an 'array' of nested lists or use `numpy arrays` which, without some effort, will convert the tuples to a new sub axis?

1st fix up typos/omissions

```
b = [[(2,1)],[(3,1)],[(3,2)],
     [(2,3)],[(3,1)],[(11,3)]]
```

list 'array' ans: (from my comment, v.coder 'answer')

```
[[(y[0],) for y in x] for x in b]

[[(2,)], [(3,)], [(3,)], [(2,)], [(3,)], [(11,)]]
```

numpy array ans:

```
a = np.array(b)

a

array([[[ 2,  1]],

       [[ 3,  1]],

       [[ 3,  2]],

       [[ 2,  3]],

       [[ 3,  1]],

       [[11,  3]]])

a.shape

(6, 1, 2)


a[...,0]

array([[ 2],
       [ 3],
       [ 3],
       [ 2],
       [ 3],
       [11]])
```